# How arrange dates from min to max in columns based on unique id column value in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

This is given data in excel
[image]

I want it in this format
[image]

Arrange dates in min to max based on unique ids in excel.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour]. You can make tables within your post [using Markdown formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and this is _much_ preferred to screenshots.

Comment: Future visitors looking for a similar solution would not benefit from a link to images. Also a little explanation of what you are trying to achieve (and what you've achieved yourself) is beneficial to you, people solving your problem and future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT

If you are using O365, then you may try using in this way as well,

Formula used in cell D2

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A10)
```

Formula used in cell E2

```
=TRANSPOSE(SORT(FILTER($B$2:$B$10,D2=$A$2:$A$10),,1))
```

**For Excel Users 2007 & 2010 & onwards**,

Formula used in cell D2 - To get UNIQUE **id**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$10,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$A$2:$A$10),0)),"")
```

Formula used in cell E2 --> To get sorted in ascending order dates based on ID,

```
=SMALL(IF($D2=$A$2:$A$10,$B$2:$B$10,""),COLUMN(A1))
```

Since its an array formula, you need to press `CTRL SHIFT ENTER` based on your excel version,

Or you may use this formula as well

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,($B$2:$B$10)/($D2=$A$2:$A$10),COLUMN(A1))
```

[image: ARRANGE_DATES]

Comment: I AM USING EXCEL2016

Comment: @datamind check the solution, i have updated and let me know please

Comment: It's Working thanks!